# Which hibernate entity inheritance strategies is required

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity

My base entity that is common part for many other entity:-

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class IdBase {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    private Instant created;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    private Instant updated;

}
```

One of the entity as follows:-

```
    @Entity
@Table(name="TBL_SUB_EMPLOYEES")
public class SubEmployeeEntity extends IdBase {

    @Column(name="sub_title")
    private String subTitle;

    @Column(name="sub_role")
    private String subRole;
}
```

My generic repository as:-

```
@Repository
public interface AuditRepository<E extends IdBase> extends JpaRepository<E, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<E> {

}
```

When I try to query SubEmployeeEntity by the generic repository I got error:-

> Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [subTitle] on this
> ManagedType [com.test.IdBase]; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with
> the the given name [subTitle] on this ManagedType [com.test.IdBase]

IdBase is common class for many entity and I kept only the common column here. I only showed SubEmployeeEntity. I have same kind of entity inherited form IdBase as well. Why is it looking for subTitle in IdBase. How do I fulfill my requirements?

Comment: `When I try to query SubEmployeeEntity by the generic repository` how exactly you try to query the repository? Did you try to enable sql logs (`hibernate.show_sql`, `hibernate.format_sql`, `hibernate.use_sql_comments`) and see what exactly jpql/sql was generated?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using JPA specifications and within the specification try to access subtype properties although the repository you are using has the type bound `IdBase`. To make this work, you would have to subclass the repository for every concrete type and also inject that subtype of repository which I guess you don't want to do. If that's the case, you should use `TREAT` in your specifications to access the subtype properties.

You have to imagine that the type variabbe has no effect as Spring can never observe what you use on your use-site. Only if create a subtype and inject that subtype, Spring can resolve the type variable to the concrete subtype. This leads to the fact that Spring creates a JPA root for the type bound `IdBase` so now you have to *treat* the alias to be able to access properties through JPA Criteria.